# Reducing code duplication in Ractive.js

Tags: javascript, ractivejs, server-side-includes

I'm running into the issue that many different pages on my website (created using Ractive.js) need the same functions, mostly functions that perform AJAX calls back to the server. I would normally store all these functions in one JS file and include it in all of my pages for common functionality, but when I do this the function aren't recognized inside my Ractive code for the individual pages.

So it looks something like this

```
<script src="src/to/common/library"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
<div id="template">
 // Ractive code
  load_models(); // defined in common library, throws error that it's not defined.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Instead of doing

```
$(function() {                                                                                                                    

    var MAIN = new Ractive({
        el: '#target',
        template: '#template',
```

I can just do

```
$.getScript("/app_name/static/js/scripts/common.js",  function() {
   var MAIN = new Ractive({
      ...
   )};

  // all functions defined in common.js are available for your use now

 });
```